# Failure to return contract in deployment script using Foundry

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge

I have a contract Lottery.sol which deploys  a contract PriceFeed.

**In Lottery.sol** :

```
contract PriceFeed {
  .....
}

contract Lottery {
  PriceFeed public price_feed = new PriceFeed();
}
```

In my Foundry deployment script which imports Lottery.sol, I made run() to return a (contract PriceFeed) as a test to see where price_feed gets deployed.

**In Deploy.s.sol** :

```
......

contract Deploy is Script {
  function run() external returns (PriceFeed) {
    vm.startBroadcast();
    Lottery lottery = new Lottery();
    vm.stopBroadcast();
    return lottery.price_feed;
  }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to build the project with forge:

```
Return argument type function () view external returns (contract PriceFeed) is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) contract PriceFeed.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
return PriceFeed(address(lottery.price_feed));
```